# How to restrict 2nd date picker no more than below the 1st date picker's selected date?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I am using Materialize's custom Pickadate datepicker.

This is my HTML and I am using Materialize css

```
<div class="col s12 m6">
    <input type="date" id="check_in" class="datepicker1">
    <label for="Check-in">Check in date</label>
</div>
<div class="col s12 m6">
    <input type="date" id="check_out" class="datepicker2">
    <label for="check_out">Check out date</label>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker1').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 1, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    min: true,
    format: 'yyyy, mmmm d'
  });

  $('.datepicker2').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 1, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    min: true,
    format: 'yyyy, mmmm d'
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Materialize's datepicker is a modified pickadate.js. If you check that plugin's docs there are `min` and `max` options: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#limits You would need to code a bit in order to reinitiaze the 2nd datepicker each time the 1st changes with the 1st date as the `min` option.

Answer (score 2):

You would run the following code when the first date picker is changed. `picker` would be your first datepicker and `picker2` would be your second datepicker. Onchange, grab the first picker's date and assign it as the minimum on the second picker.

```
var date = picker.get()
picker2.set('min', date)
```

http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/